# how to enable screen/desktop capture in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, getusermedia

I am able to achive it in firefox by folowing below steps:

1. make my server `https`
2. append my domain to the user preference  `media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains` in `about:config` to whitelist it for screen sharing.
3. use constraint like `{video: {mediaSource: "screen"}}`,

but in chrome, I am getting totally lost.

most places keep telling:  You'll need to first enable the flag called Enable screen capture support in getUserMedia() in chrome://flags. ( but I am **unable** to find this flag anywhere)

I have checked Muaz Khan's [screen share plugin](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Chrome-Extensions/tree/master/desktopCapture), it works great, but afraid that it is coupled with other WebRTC experiment projects, and I am not sure how to customize the plugin to my project.

At this junction, I have come to an understanding that, without plug-in or flags, cannot capture the desktop mediastream.

so what I would like to know is, what is the flag I must enable/ what must be part of a plug-in written from scratch to make chrome support capturing desktop the same way it allows us to capture camera.

Comment: This is why you cannot find anymore https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347641

Comment: Just to confirm, [that plugin](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Chrome-Extensions/tree/master/desktopCapture) isn't having any single dependency. It is 100% standalone; and it can be used within any 3rd party WebRTC code. Many "big-well-known" companies are already using it in their products :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Chrome/Chromium you cannot use "standard" Javascript to capture users screen anymore.

It was replaced by the [chrome.desktopCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture), which is exclusive for Chrome extensions.

The example you're providing rely in this API and an extensions. It's plugin free but not extension free.

Answer (score 2):

The `enable-usermedia-screen-capture` flag was removed from `chrome://flags/` in Chrome M36 ([Chromium Issue 347641](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347641)).

For testing or experimenting, the feature can still be enabled when starting Chrome with `chrome --enable-usermedia-screen-capturing` (tested in Chrome 68).

**Screenshot:**

[image]

The [Chrome Platform Status](https://www.chromestatus.com/) also highlights a [MediaStream.getDisplayMedia()](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6744724455030784) implementation, which will allow developers to record or share the screen from the browser without any plugin. The specification for this can be found in the [Screen Capture Editor's Draft](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/).