# WebRTC/WebSocket screen recording

Tags: websocket, html5-video, webrtc, video-capture

In my use case I would like to record the screen activity and send it to server [not live]. I looked at few blogs/sample demos for this. But I couldn't find anything related to this. I could find lot of live streaming audio/video but not screen recording.

I have the following questions related to this,

- Which one would be efficient WebRTC/Websockets for this use case?
- Browser support for WebRTC/Websockets?
- Is there any other methods to achieve this use case?

I am fairly new to WebRTC/Websockets, if I am not posting the enough information please comment. I will add.

Could someone help me on this? Any reference URL/any related info related to this use case would be really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to record the screen in Firefox (**Update:** try it in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/mt98yos9/)):

```js
var constraints = { video: { mediaSource: "screen", width: 320, height: 200 } };

var start = ms => navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(stream => record(stream, ms)
    .then(recording => {
      stop(stream);
      video.src = link.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(recording));
      link.download = "recording.blob";
      link.innerHTML = "Download blob";
      log("Playing "+ recording[0].type +" recording:");
    })
    .catch(log).then(() => stop(stream)))
  .catch(log);

var record = (stream, ms) => {
  var rec = new MediaRecorder(stream), data = [];
  rec.ondataavailable = e => data.push(e.data);
  rec.start();
  log(rec.state + " for "+ (ms / 1000) +" seconds...");
  var stopped = new Promise((r, e) => (rec.onstop = r, rec.onerror = e));
  return Promise.all([stopped, wait(ms).then(() => rec.stop())])
    .then(() => data);
};

var stop = stream => stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
```

```html
<button onclick="start(5000)">Record screen!</button>
<div id="div"></div><br>
<video id="video" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video>
<a id="link"></a>
```

> **Warning:** Sharing your browser window on the web involves security risk! Read about it [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/share-browser-windows-entire-screen-sites-trust/)!

Once you have the blob, you can upload it using regular web sockets (not shown).

The [mediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) bits should work in Chrome as well, but unfortunately screensharing is still not fully standardized and works differently and requires an extension in Chrome.

Comment: It helps a lot. Is it possible to test this in localhost I mean without https?

Comment: @Dany, yes, but only if you add `,localhost` to the list of domains, and set `media.navigator.permission.disabled` to `true` in *about:config*. The latter turns off all getUserMedia permissions, so you probably want to set it back after testing.

Comment: this records from the camera for some reason

Comment: @JimmyKane Only works in Firefox, as stated. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/41881434/918910.

Comment: @jib Right! and thanks for the edit. Also maybe noteworthy to add https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466639/how-to-enable-screen-desktop-capture-in-chrome

Answer (score 4):

The solution can be divided into three parts:

- getting hold of screen mediastream using getUserMedia, this falls under category of WebRTC, and since you are sharing screen, your site is gonna have to be `https` and your users probably going to need to use extensions( for both firefox and chrome), you could look for demo [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/screen-sharing/)
- Recording the mediastream, firefox has been supporting this for a while through [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) and heard chrome started supporting it from 47. So with mediarecorder, you can get hold of blob of your recorded file.
- How you post this blob to server is totally up to you, you could use any channel: websockets, http post, etc. You could make the server a WebRTC client, and send it through RTCDataChannel, but guessing that would be overkill for your use case.

Comment: Thank you. It is really helpful.

Comment: how to record whole screen which means not only the firefox or any other broweer window , i want to record the whole screen of end user.

Comment: @vaishali did you check the link to demo( in the first point)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @mido, in the client side I would use MediaRecorder API. Another option would be to record in the server side. For the latter option, you can use some open source media server, like [Kurento] (http://www.kurento.org/).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other server side recording tools? I just want to find the best one. I am fairly new to this area.

Comment: @DineshAppavoo , you can also give a try to [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/recordplaytest.html), another open source project that, by the way, has important activity in the [Github repository](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway)