# Getting image data from webRTC stream

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I am working on a webrtc screen sharing application. I have an extension which does the following :

```
desktopMediaRequestId = chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(data_sources, tab, function(streamId) {
if (streamId) {
  msg.type = 'SUCESS';
  msg.streamId = streamId;
} else {
  msg.type = 'FAILURE';
}
port.postMessage(msg);});
```

I can use this stream id to share the screen. But is there anyway I can get image-data with this stream id?

Comment: [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) should [do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36484696/918910).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebRTC/WebSocket screen recording](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857134/webrtc-websocket-screen-recording)